# How to bind AJAX data to a Flask Python App?

Tags: jquery, python, html, ajax, flask

I am doing some groundwork on building my first python flask web application. I have sorted out most of the details I need on the server side, but I have few questions on how to implement things on client side.

My Application is going to be a single page application with data populated dynamically depending on user action.

Say, I have a template called index.html which has a menu selection on left hand side and a table structure on the right hand side of the template. When an user selects an option from menu, I will post an AJAX request from the client to server and the flask app routes returns a JSON response.

This is where my issue is. I know how to fill in a table data when rendering a page.I can use

```
render_template('index.html',tabledata = tabledata )
```

in my server side to send table data and use

```
{% for data in tabledata %}
<tr> data </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

in my client side, I can use a code as above.

But since I am planning to use AJAX requests, I am not sure how to populate the table data returned from AJAX request in already rendered flask template.

I searched for answer and I have found out that I have to build the table dynamically using Javascript. But I want to know is there any better way to fill in the template? I am trying to avoid building html table using javascript.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to fetch the rendered table over AJAX? Or do you want to fetch JSON and build the table client-side?

Comment: Flask has little to do with what your client-side Javascript code does. Once the template is rendered, the browser sees HTML and CSS and Javascript.

Comment: Your AJAX call can load a whole HTML table from the Flask server of course, just have another endpoint produce that output instead of, say, JSON for the client to render into HTML.

Comment: I was thinking about loading the data and let the client handle the table generation.Never thought of sending the whole table structure from server. Could you please guide me how it can be done? I am trying to avoid reloading the page again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate a table using data using AJAX, it's generally recommended to use JSON for API endpoints (adding an XSS to your site by inserting HTML into the DOM is a bad idea). You can do this by simply returning a dictionary ([you shouldn't ever return JSON lists from an endpoint](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/1009)), like so:

```
@app.route("/some/url")
def route():
    return flask.jsonify(**{"a": "dict", "returned": "becomes", "a": "JSON object"})
```

You can then use AJAX to get the object and populate your table using JavaScript. You should note that Flask has nothing to do with client-side code (apart from serving it to the client).